# PHP combine 2 table like arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I would like to combine 2 arrays into 1 in PHP. I've searched this site for similar questions but can't seem to find an answer.

```
Array 1
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [LOGIN] => 123
        [CITY] => bangkok
        [GROUP] => bangkok-a
        [PREV_A] => 123.4
        [PREV_B] => 456.7
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [LOGIN] => 456
        [CITY] => bangkok
        [GROUP] => bangkok-b
        [PREV_A] => 987.6
        [PREV_B] => 654.3
    )
)

Array 2
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [LOGIN] => 123
        [CITY] => bangkok
        [GROUP] => bangkok-a
        [A] => 555.5
        [B] => 666.6
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [LOGIN] => 456
        [CITY] => bangkok
        [GROUP] => bangkok-b
        [A] => 777.7
        [B] => 888.8
    )
)
```

I want the resulting arrays become like this:

```
Array 3
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [LOGIN] => 123
        [CITY] => bangkok
        [GROUP] => bangkok-a
        [PREV_A] => 123.4
        [PREV_B] => 456.7
        [A] => 555.5
        [B] => 666.6
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [LOGIN] => 456
        [CITY] => bangkok
        [GROUP] => bangkok-b
        [PREV_A] => 987.6
        [PREV_B] => 654.3
        [A] => 777.7
        [B] => 888.8
    )
)
```

Each array is 64. I've tried this code but the resulting array has 4096 (=64x64) fields and not 64.

```
foreach($arr1 as $x){
    foreach($arr2 as $y){
        if ($x['LOGIN']=$y['LOGIN']){
            $tmp=array();
            $tmp=array_merge($x,$y);
            array_push($res,$tmp);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I combine them correctly? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$newArray = Array();
foreach($arr1 as $k=>$val)
{
    if(array_key_exists($k, $arr2))
    {
        $newArray[$k] = array_merge($val, $arr2[$k]);
    }
}
```

Haven't tested, but I think it should work...

Comment: You Sir, are amazing. That works like wonder! :D Thank you very much. +1 and answered.